# Почему объект, реализующий Iterable, ведет себя как множество?

Tags: java, итераторы

У меня есть код, в котором экземпляр класса, реализующего интерфейс `Iterable`, помещен в цикл `foreach`, и это не только не вызывает у компилятора возражений, но оно еще и работает. Но как - я не понимаю.

Код

```
class ArrayIterator implements Iterator {
    private int index = 0;
    private final int[] values;

    ArrayIterator(int[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < values.length;
    }

    public Object next() {
        return values[index++];
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
    }
}

class ForEachArray implements Iterable {
    private final int[] values;

    ForEachArray(final int[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator(this.values);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForEachArray forEach = new ForEachArray(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
        for (Object value : forEach) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Выводит:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Почему экземпляр класса, который не является ни массивом, ни коллекцией, попав в цикл на место множества, работает как множество? Что происходит в потоке выполнения? Как получается, что цикл `for` умудряется вызвать сначала метод `iterator()` у `ForEachArray` (ну это еще ладно: на то он и `Iterable`), а потом еще и `hasNext()` и `next()` у `ArrayIterator`? Вот что непонятно.

Comment: Вот вы сами и объяснили все. Осталось только поверить, что так оно и есть.

Comment: Почитайте как работает цикл `for` в Java в любом современном учебнике.

Comment: Я не понимаю почему он hasNext() и next() цепляет. Они же вообще в другом классе находятся.

Comment: Потому что так и должно происходить.

Comment: @Павел это всё происходит внутри реализации foreach. Таким вот образом он работает. Получение итератора и использование его (его методов) в цикле.

Comment: [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: Ага... тоесть если бы у меня не ArrayIterator не был implements Iterator то все упало бы..?

Comment: Безусловно. Хотя бы потому, что вы бы не смогли его возвращать в методе `public Iterator iterator()`. А если бы вы неправильно реализовали его (методы `hasNext` и `next`), то и нормально пробежаться по элементам `ForEachArray` не получилось бы.

Comment: https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/enhanced-for.html

Comment: @PavelMayorov В каком учебнике говориться прямым текстом про итераторы? Везде только массивы и коллекции. Хотя конечно можно догадаться, что коллекции перебираются с помощью итератора, ибо другого варианта просто нет.

Comment: @Sergey ни разу не видел чтобы замалчивалась связь этой формы цикла for и интерфейса Iterable

Comment: @PavelMayorov я наоборот ни разу не встречал. В лучшем случае есть упоминание процесса "итерация коллекции", но про интерфейс Iterable вообще ни слова. Только в каких-то отдельных статьях, и то когда ищешь по ключевому слову "Iterable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For-Each цикл

```
for (Object value : forEach) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

работает [таким образом](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

```
for (Iterator i = forEach.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
{
    Object value = i.next();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Метод `iterator` класса `ForEachArray` у вас возвращает `ArrayIterator`. Соответственно, методы `hasNext` и `next` вызываются как раз у `ArrayIterator`.